# How to break on beep in Swift?

Tags: swift, debugging, alert

It sometimes happens that your code is causing an alert sound with no console logging or any other indication of what's wrong. In Objective-C, you could break on `NSBeep()` to find out why this was happening. However, this doesn't seem to be working in Swift 4.

How can I get Swift to break when a beep is played to see the stack that caused it?

Comment: When a beep is played? I'm not aware of any beeps in Xcode.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've heard an app make an alert sound! Funk, Sosumi, Tink, etc. I'm calling it a beep because the Objective-C function is `NSBeep()`.